# sonarqube code analysis with angularJS

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I need to analyse angularJS code with sonarqube, but how? there is no               plugin available for angularJS in sonarqube.

I have tried to find possible solution but it is not helping anymore.

Comment: Do you use typescript?

Comment: nope, i dont know about it, will you please let me know?

Comment: I search on typescript, but there is also no plugin available of TS in sonarqube, I found one third party plugin but it is not working. will you please suggest me right way to achieve code analysis of angular project with enough explanation

Answer (score 0):

[SonarJS](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Plugin) is a plugin for analysing JavaScript code. Anyway it does not provide any rules specific for AngularJS framework.